# Insert csv file into SQL Server database: error with listdir?

Tags: sql-server, csv, pypyodbc

I know it's bad to throw code here and ask for help to trouble shoot. This problem seems a little over my head.

The code is supposed to loop through all the files and sub folders. I don't think there is any log error here. The problem is I ran into problem that same file is processed again and caused the DB insert failed on primary key constraint.

This is my code:

```
import csv
import pypyodbc
import os
import sys

extension = ".tsv"
connStr = """DSN=database_test;"""

sys.stdout = open('c:\\temp\\python.log', 'w')
print 'starting ...'

def LoadFile(path):   
    i = 0 
    for item in os.listdir(path): # loop through items in dir        
        full_path = os.path.join(path, item)
        if os.path.isfile(full_path) and full_path.endswith(extension): # check for ".tsv" extension

            if full_path.find('IM') > 0:
                table_name = 'table_a'
            else:
                table_name = 'table_b'

            if os.stat(full_path).st_size > 0:
                print "Processing file:", i, "|", full_path
                i = i + 1
                with open (full_path, 'r') as f:
                    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
                    columns = next(reader) 
                    query = 'insert into ' + table_name + '({0}) values ({1})'
                    crsr = cnxn.cursor()
                    for data in reader:
                        query = query.format(', '.join(columns), ', '.join('?' * len(columns)))          
                        #print(query, "with ", data)
                        if(data[1] != ''):
                            crsr.execute(query, data)
                    crsr.commit()  
                    crsr.close()                                
        elif os.path.isdir(full_path):                        
            print "Process Folder: ", full_path    
            LoadFile(full_path)                        
        else:
            print("invalid file name:", item)
    print "Process Folder total files: ", i, ":", full_path
    return         

cnxn = pypyodbc.connect(connStr)

dir_name = 'X:\\TopLevelFolder'
LoadFile(dir_name)

cnxn.close()
print("Completed")
```

Comment: the logging does not work as I expected. but this is not the show stopper.

Comment: Nobody respond? I did another test. I created a same folder structure on a local drive, and copied a couple of files over. I ran the same code and it worked just fine.

Comment: each folder has about 5000 files. Will that create problem for python list? Another thing is the 32 bit vs 64 bit. I am on a 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original question was a little misleading... the code didn't work because of some hardware issues that cannot be explained. After I switched to python 2.7 and reinstalled all the libraries. The code is working fine.